Error in iguanatext: ! pdfTeX error (\pdfsave): not allowed in DVI mode
Why do I get this error in IguanaText?

The code does work, I only get the error when I use IguanaText. Thanks for the help.
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$\unslant\alpha \unslant\pi$
\end{document}


You are generating dvi not pdf but have the pdf-specific command  \pdfsave

please paste errors as text.
